# I need this variable to take to view for comparing

Tags: php, laravel, view, foreach, laravel-blade

I have this code

```
foreach ($test_results as $question_result) {
    if($question_result == 1){
        $correct_question =1;
    }
    else
    {
        $correct_question =0;
    }
}
```

and so far this is good when I try with `dd($correct_question);` it shows me if it is correct or not, but I want that to display in view I have this view

```
@foreach($test_questions as $question)
    @foreach ($test_results as $question_result)
        @if($correct_question)
            <i id="checki" class="fa fa-check"></i> 
        @else
            <i id="remove" class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I dont know how to send to the view with something like this or I dont know can anyone please help me..? thank you.

```
return view('website.tests.take.take-test-results')->with([
    'results'          => $test_results,
    'test_questions'   => $test_questions,
    'correct_question' => $correct_question,
]);
```

Comment: Take a step back and review your code logic. It makes no sense. Try explaining it to us step by step. That usually helps you figure out what you're doing better.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as follow :

```
 @foreach ($test_results as $question_result)
    @if($question_result == 1)
        <i id="checki" class="fa fa-check"></i> 
    @else
        <i id="remove" class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
@foreach($test_questions as $question)
    @if(in_array($question, $correct_question))
        <i id="checki" class="fa fa-check"></i> 
    @else
        <i id="remove" class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**NOTE**: If your `$question` having id and your `$correct_question` having array of correct question/answer, you can try `@if(in_array($question['id'], $correct_question))`